# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje cuando la tabla está vacía?

Tags: html, css

Quiero mostrar un mensaje cuando la tabla esté vacía, por medio de css.

```css
table > tbody:empty {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    text-align: center;
}
table > tbody:empty:before {
    content: 'SIN DATOS';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Lugar</th>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Persona</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Es solo que tbody toma el width de la primer columna.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo que tome todas las columnas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como el `tbody` lo tienes vacío puedes hacer que se comporte como un caption (título de tabla) y establecerlo al fondo de la tabla. De esta manera, dará la sensación de que todo el contenido de la tabla es un texto.

Esto lo conseguirás con estas dos propiedades:

```
display: table-caption;
caption-side: bottom;
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
table > tbody:empty {
    position: relative;
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    text-align: center;
}
table > tbody:empty:before {
    content: 'SIN DATOS';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Lugar</th>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Persona</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excelente. Funcionó.